# Spring-boot jar return whitelabel error when run on Linux

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I have a problem with my spring-boot app, when I try to deploy and run the JAR on a Linux server it returns me a whiteLabel error whereas when I run it on my local windows computer it doesn't have any problem.

Below the error displayed in the web page (no error returned on the server side) :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 26 09:03:01 UTC 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/advisor/home.jsp
```

Controller method which returns the home page

```
@GetMapping("home")
    public String getHomePage(){
        return "/advisor/home";
    }
```

Application.properties

```
logging.level.root=INFO
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Project structure
[image]

I don't understand why the jar works fine on my local computer but can't find the views when run on the Linux server

Comment: show how you call/define your JSP and what is the case of home.jsp file and advisor directory?

Comment: I have added some precision, but i really don't understand why the jar don't run on the server whereas the same jar works fine on the local computer

Comment: Where's home.jsp?

Comment: in advisor folder , that's why my method return advisor/home

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, instead of a war I have generated a jar when I generate a war the problem resolved himself.